# Understanding WPF data binding and value converter interactions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to understand what's actually happening behind the scenes on the simplified repro code below.

I have a single `Window` with a `ListBox` and a `TextBlock` that are bound together (i.e., master -> detail). I then have a ViewModel with a couple properties--a string and a date. For the date, I implemented a value converter (`LongDateConverter`).

I have a couple `Debug.WriteLine()` calls in the code that lead to the following output:

- Launch app

  - `In converter: ConverterProblem.MainWindowViewModel`
  - `In converter: null`
- Click on one of the two items in the list box

  - `In converter: ConverterProblem.DataModel`

The second and third calls to the `IValueConverter` method I think I understand. The second is `null` because the `ListBox` doesn't have a selected item yet. The third is for the item that I selected.

What I don't understand is:

1. Why is the first call passed a value of type `MainWindowViewModel`?
2. Why is that call even happening in the first place?

Here's my code:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="ConverterProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:ConverterProblem"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <app:LongDateConverter x:Key="longDateConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Data}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource longDateConverter}}" 
                   DataContext="{Binding Data}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ConverterProblem 
{
    public class LongDateConverter : IValueConverter 
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        {
            if (value == null) {
                Debug.WriteLine("In converter: null");
                return "null";
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("In converter: " + value.GetType().ToString());

            if (value.GetType() == typeof(MainWindowViewModel))
                return "viewmodel";

            return ((DataModel)value).Date.ToLongDateString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DataModel _data;
        private List<DataModel> _dataList;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _dataList = new List<DataModel> { 
                new DataModel { Date = DateTime.Now, Name = "John" }, 
                new DataModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50), Name = "Sue" }
            };
        }

        public DataModel Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                if (_data == value) return;

                _data = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }

        public List<DataModel> DataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using MVVMLight, or your own MVVM?

Comment: @Darek, my own. The code I shared in a vanilla WPF app is all there is to it.

Comment: It will be more difficult to figure out without seeing the code. There must be a reason why your converter receives MainWindowViewModel in the first iteration. Do you assign data context anywhere?

Comment: Show us where and how your view gets 'connected' to your viewmodel. Add the code to question please.

Comment: I actually did share all of the code. :) It was connecting in MainWindow's constructor and also in TextBlock. What Rohit shared in his answer turned out to be what I was missing. Thanks for the help though, guys.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Issue is you have binded **`Text`** dependency prior of setting **`DataContext`** for TextBlock.

XAML files are compiled into BAML and on application run, it is loaded from BAML by **`XAMLLoader`** which ***parse XAML from top to bottom and set value for DP's accordingly***.

Since, Text DP gets encountered first so it will try to first set it's value and DataContext is not set yet for TextBlock so it will inherit from its parent Window whose DataContext is set to MainWindowViewModel. Hence, you see MainWindowViewModel printed in your converter. And when DataContext is set all DP's binding will be re-evaluated as per new DataContext.

---

Replace your XAML to this and you will see **`MainWindowViewModel`** won't print any more:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Data}"
           Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource longDateConverter}}" />
```

*Output*:

```
In converter: null
In converter: ConverterProblem.DataModel
```

Comment: Didn't know the order of the actual attributes in the elements made a difference. Thanks a lot for the details!